# PHP str_getcsv doesn't separate elements in the index 1 and 2

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm importing a CSV and creating a 2D array with it. 
The problem is that in the indexes 1 and 2 the function doesn't recognize the separator "," so every array is ok but the ones in the second and third position.

I tried with multiple files, multiple software (LibreOffice, Google Spreadsheet) and it has always the same problem.

This is the code:

```
$dbLocation = 'upload/db.csv';

$paramStrGetCsv = array(",", '"', "\\");
$db = array_map('str_getcsv', file($dbLocation), $paramStrGetCsv);

print "<pre>";
print_r($db);
print "</pre>";
```

This is the array $db:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => email
            [1] => name
            [2] => surname
            [3] => birthdate
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => red@email.com,red,qwer,1990-06-01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue@gmail.com,blue,poiu,1990-01-01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => green@yahoo.com
            [1] => green
            [2] => yuiop
            [3] => 1980-01-01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => purple@gmail.com
            [1] => purple
            [2] => zxcvbn
            [3] => 1975-01-01
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => yellow@gmail.com
            [1] => yellow
            [2] => vbnm
            [3] => 1970-01-01
        )
)
```

This is the csv file:

```
email,name,surname,birthdate
red@email.com,red,qwer,1990-06-01
blue@gmail.com,blue,poiu,1990-01-01
green@yahoo.com,green,yuiop,1980-01-01
purple@gmail.com,purple,zxcvbn,1975-01-01
yellow@gmail.com,yellow,vbnm,1970-01-01
```

Thank you,
Federico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's your problem:

```
$db = array_map('str_getcsv', file($dbLocation), $paramStrGetCsv);
```

First entry will run function `str_getcsv("email,name,surname,birthdate", ",")`

Second will run `str_getcsv(red@email.com,red,qwer,1990-06-01, "\"")`

and generally array map maps mutliple arrays using a single function which accepts multiple arguments, so it will try to use both the file and the `$paramStrGetCsv` to do the mapping. Instead do this:

```
$db = array_map(function ($ln) { return str_getcsv($ln,",", '"', "\\"); }, file($dbLocation));
```